# Add integer value to Shared prefference

Tags: android

Im creating a alarm app that will have multiple alarm.. so i want to store the times in shared preference. if there is any solution to store integer list in shared preference

Comment: @Danieboy not tried anything i want create alarms and it must show in home activity

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("key", yourIntValue);
editor.apply();
```

Use `editor.apply()` to save preferences asynchronously. `apply()` is preferable in the most cases.

Use `editor.commit()` to save preferences synchronously.

Comment: i want to list all alarms created ?

Comment: SharedPreferences are a key-value storage. By code above you are adding key - int value pair. Not key - int list pair. You have 3 options. 1. save each alarm with different key (bad idea); 2. Save them as string set using putStringSet; 3. Use database, file etc instead of sharedPreferences